# MVC3 incrementing a variable in javascript(Jquery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to create a form inside a table that adds a new row every time content is added to the form. Here's my code, and then I'll tell what the problem is.

```
@{
    //Declare the i variable
    var i = 0;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>

            </th>
            <th>
                Question
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="@(i+1)">
            <td class="QuestionNum">
                @(i+1))
            </td>
            //This is the cell with the Form field. 
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Questions[i].Question, new { @class = "QuestionBox Last" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SetUpNewLine($('.QuestionBox'));
    });

    function SetUpNewLine(obj) {
        obj.bind('keyup paste', function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                if ($(this).hasClass("Last")) {

                    //This is the line that isn't working.
                    @(i++)

                    $(this).parents('table').append('<tr id="@(i+1)"><td class="QuestionNum">@(i+1))</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Questions[i], new { @class = "QuestionBox Last", style="width:100%;" })</td></tr>');
                    $(this).removeClass('Last');
                    SetUpNewLine($('.Last'));
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

So, this code works for the first time, but when calling the `@(i++)` in the Javascript function, it doesn't save the variable change once you get outside of the function. So after the first Html.TextBoxFor, which is for the first item in the Model.Questions object, it does create a new textbox like I wanted, but instead of incrementing the item it changes in the List, it makes them all just edit the second item in the list.

The odd thing is that if I was to do the `@(i++)` inside the `$(document).ready()`, it would work fine.

Any ideas on how I could increment the variable correctly? I'm sure there's just something I don't know when it comes to mixing Razor variables and Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the server rendered value of `i` in javascript.

**EDIT**
This is all wrong. You won't be able to append to your element with razor syntax like you are trying to do. Razor is a server side template language and once it is interpreted to HTML, you can render more HTML from the client side.

**EDIT 2**
Try something like the following:

```
var current_index = (@i);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SetUpNewLine($('.QuestionBox'));
    });

    function getHtml(index){
        return '<tr id="' +index + '"><td class="QuestionNum">'+ index +'</td><td><input type="text" name="Question" class="QuestionBox Last" style="width:100%;"/></td></tr>';
    }

    function SetUpNewLine(obj) {
        obj.bind('keyup paste', function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                if ($(this).hasClass("Last")) {

                    //This is the line that isn't working.
                    current_index++;

                    $(this).parents('table').append(getHtml(current_index);
                    $(this).removeClass('Last');
                    SetUpNewLine($('.Last'));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Then how would I put the variable into the HtmlHelper?

Comment: Oh, so in the Javascript, instead of using the HtmlHelper I should hard code the <input> so that it fits the model on postback?

Comment: Yes. MVC will use a model binder to fill out your model for you.

Comment: That looks really clean! One question though, would this take into account that it's adding it into a `List<string>`?

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of the variable in a hidden form field, so when the form is posted to the server, the incremented value of this variable is sent as well.

```
<input type="hidden" name="incrementedVar" value="1" />
```

Javascript to increment it:

```
$("input[name='incrementedVar']").val($("input[name='incrementedVar']").val() + 1);
```

and get the value in your controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int incrementedVar)
{
    // the incrementedVar param matches the name of the hidden field. 
    // the model binder will automatically pass the value of the hidden field to this param.
}
```

Using this code, the variable is controlled entirely by javascript, and the server only gets access to it on postback.  You'll need to remove the razor declaration and incrementing code that you currently have.

Comment: I don't want a postback to the server every time I want a new row to show though.

Comment: It won't post back every time, only when you submit the form.  If you don't need access to the counter on the serverside, you can just use a javascript var and increment that.

Comment: If i use a javascript variable, then I can't put it into the Html.TextBoxFor as the index of the item it's editing in the array can I?